# my application Laravel 6 does not want to save items in the session properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have save in the session but for some reason the session only saves after insisting on sending the item to the session.

If I don't insist he won't save.
In some cases it even saves on the first attempt, but usually it doesn't.

What can it be?
this is my code for saving cart items in the session:

```
if(!$request->session()->has('cart')){
          $request->session()->put('cart', []);
          $request->session()->save();
          $car = [];
        }else{
            $car = $request->session()->get('cart');
            $request->session()->save();
        }
if($request->input('buscarporid')){
            $produto =   Produto::where('id',$request->input('buscarporid'))->first();
            $produto['search'] = $produto->nome_comercial. '  '.  $produto->descricao. '  [ '.$produto->categoria->nome.' ]  -  '.$produto->ean_1.' - [ R$ '.number_format($produto->preco_venda, 2, ',', '.').' ]';
        }else{
            $produto =   Produto::where('ean_1',$request->input('ean'))->first();
            $produto['search'] = $produto->nome_comercial. '  '.  $produto->descricao. '  [ '.$produto->categoria->nome.' ]  -  '.$produto->ean_1.' - [ R$ '.number_format($produto->preco_venda, 2, ',', '.').' ]';
        }

        if($produto && $request->session()->has('cart')) {
            if (count($car) > 0) {
                foreach ($car as $index => $item) {
                    if ($item['id'] == $produto->id && $feito == false) {
                        $car[$index]->qtd_saida += $request->input('qtd_saida');
                        $request->session()->put('cart', $car);
                        $request->session()->save();
                        $feito = true;
                    }

                }

            }
            if ($feito == false){
                $produto->qtd_saida = $request->input('qtd_saida');
                $request->session()->push('cart', $produto);
                $request->session()->save();

            }
              return $request->session()->get('cart');
        }else{
            return (new ClasseTerapeuticaResource([]))
                ->response()
                ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
```

On my local machine it works normally.

Note: I already tried with session file and session database. the problem is the same.
I'm using Laravel 6

Comment: You can try using [Session facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)

Comment: @SebastiánPérez `$request->session()` uses the same system.

Comment: @SebastiánPérez I tried to do that too, but it didn't work.
The strange thing is that the item is saved after insisting.
If I did not save in any way I would even understand that it is a permission error etc.
but he saves insistently.

Comment: I remember I had that problem once, and it was because of the load balancer in production. The solution was to save sessions in database.

Comment: @SebastiánPérez
I already tried to save from the database with the drive database, but the problem was the same.
Very strange.

Comment: @RafaelFurtado What session driver are you using?

Comment: @ceejayoz database